# What is fully connected layer additive bias?

Tags: neural-network

I'm going to use PyTorch specifically but I suspect my question applies to deep learning & CNNs in general therefore I choose to post it here.

Starting at this point in this video and subsequently:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRlyw6LO5qo&t=1370s

George H. explains that the PyTorch function `torch.nn.Linear` with the `bias` parameter set to `False` then makes the `torch.nn.Linear` functionally equivalent (other than GPU support of course) to the following NumPy line:

```
x = np.dot(weights, x) + biases
```

Note that in `torch.nn.Linear` bias by default is set to `True`:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html

Here is the PyTorch documentation for the bias parameter:

> bias – If set to False, the layer will not learn an additive bias.
> Default: True

Can anybody please explain what "additive bias" is?  In other words, what additional steps is PyTorch doing if `torch.nn.Linear` `bias` parameter set to `True`?  Surprisingly I was not able to find much on this topic upon Googleing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably misanderstood the video, it is not said that a linear layer with Bias set to False is equivalent to :

```
x = np.dot(weights, x) + biases
```

Because that is not true, a layer without Bias is equivalent to

```
x = np.dot(weights, x)
```

The way he recreates the layer without Bias is actually with the following function :

```
x = x.dot(l1)  # X = W1.X  First linear layer
x = np.maximum(x, 0)  # X = ReLU(X)
x = x.dot(l2)  # X = W2.X  Second linear layer
```

Setting Bias=True means the layer has the second bias term it adds after multiplying the weights with the input (as in the formula you quoted) :

```
x = np.dot(weights, x) + biases
```